# How can i add push button to each and every item of the list view

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

Here is my sample code,i want to add a push button to each and every row of the list view.I am not found any method to set the widget to model.Can any one please help me how to add widget for  each and every row of the list view.Thank you in advance.

Given below is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
class MyCustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MyCustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.row = QHBoxLayout()
        self.row.addWidget(QPushButton("add"))
        self.setLayout(self.row)
class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        vLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        hLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.filter = QtGui.QPushButton("filter", self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.filter)
        self.list = QtGui.QListView(self)
        vLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        vLayout.addWidget(self.list)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.list)
        codes = [
            'windows',
            'windows xp',
            'windows7',
            'hai',
            'habit',
            'hack',
            'good'
        ]
        self.list.setModel(self.model)
        for code in codes:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(code)
            self.model.appendRow(item)
            self.list.setIndexWidget(item.index(), QtGui.QPushButton("button"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: actually i tried but list view doesn't have set item widget

Comment: use `self.list.setIndexWidget(item.index(), QtGui.QPushButton("button"))`

Comment: where i should add this line sir ?i added this line after adding the item but it is not adding button

Comment: move `self.list.setModel(self.model)` before `for code in codes:`

Comment: after adding i  got only buttons not my list of items

Comment: What do you want to get? you say you want to show a button, you could show a picture of what you want to get

Comment: sir actually i want to add push button to my each item ex: windows----  "add buttons"

Comment: Well I recommend you take the time and write your question better, edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a custom widget where you must set the button on the right side with a layout.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class CustomWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("button")
        lay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        vLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        hLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.filter = QtGui.QPushButton("filter", self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.filter)
        self.list = QtGui.QListView(self)
        vLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        vLayout.addWidget(self.list)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.list)
        codes = [
            'windows',
            'windows xp',
            'windows7',
            'hai',
            'habit',
            'hack',
            'good'
        ]
        self.list.setModel(self.model)
        for code in codes:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(code)
            self.model.appendRow(item)
            self.list.setIndexWidget(item.index(), CustomWidget())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to delete the selected Item by pressing the button next to it? I tried to add a function to remove Item from QlistView  and It works but when I associate it with the button in CustomWidget it crashes. Please help me if you can